# URL rewriting for mobile devices

Tags: iphone, android, css, .htaccess, mobile-website

I know that this question has a been asked many times, but I still can't figure out what's going wrong in my code.

I have a stylesheet link on my HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

And I want to redirect to another file if the user is on a mobile device.
I did it this way:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/style.css$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /mobile.css [L,R=302]
```

My files are all in the root of a subdomain, so I guess that the rule `!^/style.css$` should be correct.

When I try to reach `/style.css`, I don't have a redirection, but when a try to reach `/`, Firefox tells me there is a redirection loop.

Do I miss something?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll work if you use Rewrite instead of Redirect:

```
RewriteEngine on   
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]  
RewriteRule ^style.css$ /mobile.css [L,NC]
```

Comment: np :) I'm ashamed to admit this type of solution had never occurred to me before reading your question.  Always good to learn something new!